# How to inject javascript into Vaadin to support addons

Tags: vaadin

Certain Vaadin addons, such as Invient Charts (https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/invient-charts), require the inclusion of javascript libraries to operate.

How can this be done without having to create a custom Servlet for Vaadin applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Scaladin addon and the Scala language, this is accomplished by the following code in the init() method on your application:

```
override def init() {
  super.init()

  // bring in javascript needed for addons
  val jqsrc = io.Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"))
  val hcsrc = io.Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/js/highcharts.js"))
  val xpsrc = io.Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/js/modules/exporting.js"))
  mainWindow.executeJavaScript((jqsrc ++ hcsrc ++ xpsrc).mkString)
  jqsrc.close(); hcsrc.close(); xpsrc.close() }
```

Note that the javascript files being opened as InputStreams must be in the classpath.  To do this using SBT, make a resources directory under the src/main dir, and put the /js dir and the .js files within.  These will be put into the WEB-INF/classes dir when the war file is built.  They will also appear in the classpath when you use container:start from the xsbt web plugin, so the same code allows for testing prior to making the .war file.

This approach should be able to work without Scala (but with a lot more Java code), but what fun would that be?

A more efficient way would be to load the JavaScript code into a string held in an object to avoid having to repeatedly read it in:

```
object Script {
  val js = Seq("/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js", "/js/highcharts.js", "/js/modules/exporting.js") map { f =>
    val in = io.Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream(f))
    val s = in.mkString
    in.close()
    s
  }
}
```

and then in the Vaadin Application:

```
class MyApp extends Application(title = "My App", applicationTheme = "reindeer")  {
  override def init() {
    super.init()

    // bring in javascript needed for addons
    Script.js foreach mainWindow.executeJavaScript
  }
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no extension point to add custom resources to the page head.

To do it anyway, you can add a Label with content mode CONTENT_RAW and any custom content like JS / CSS there. If needed you can add content to the head with

`document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild()`.

Answer (score 0):

In Vaadin 6 you have two options:

1. The option you already mentioned: extend Vaadin servlet
2. Include the files into your compiled widgetset:

Create a directy called public under the folder that contains the .gwt.xml file and client dir. Copy the files you want to include into your widgetset here. Most likely these files are js and css files and maybe some pictures. All files under this directy will be copied to the compiled widgetset.

And if you want that a js file is included to your Vaadin app, add the following line to the .gwt.xml file (src is relative to the public folder):

```
<script src="jquery/jquery.js" />
```

Comment: The second choice is an interesting idea.  I didn't try it, though.  The first choice was unappealing, as I test using the xsbt web plugin with the Vaadin app running as a servlet, but plan to deploy as a portlet, and don't want to have to make custom versions of both (or either if it can be avoided).